# Регулярное выражение не пропускает половину кириллицы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. У меня вконец съехала крыша, не могу понять, что происходит.

Имеется код, например:

```
<?php
$name = "а";
if(!preg_match('/^[а-я]*$/i', $name))
    echo 'неок!';
else
    echo 'ок!';
?>
```

так вот. если в переменной $name находятся символы [а-о] кириллицы, то регулярка их ПРОПУСКАЕТ. А если присутствуют символы дальше ([п-я]) - не пропускает. Никак не могу понять, что происходит.
Кодировка файла - utf-8
В .htaccess прописана utf-8
В браузере настроена utf-8 даже

помогите, никак не могу понять, что за фигня, уже раз 35 побился головой об стену.

**UDP**  спасибо, по юникоду понял. а если я работаю с cp1251? там вылазит та же проблема.

Comment: включите юникод в регулярке

    '/^[а-я]*$/iu'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работаете с юникодом? Добавьте флаг `/u` и будет вам счастье. Плюс для кириллицы флаг `/i` не работает и вы забыли букву `Ё`.

```php
<?php
$name = "а";
if (!preg_match('/^[а-яА-ЯёЁ]*$/u', $name)) {
    echo 'неок!';
} else {
    echo 'ок!';
}
?>
```

**update**: пардон, относительно флага `/i` ошибся. С кодировкой что-то не то было.

Comment: > Плюс для кириллицы флаг /i не работает

Это [почему же][1]?

   [1]:http://ideone.com/Id7OFL

Comment: @Deonis, сам где-то ошибся, когда тестировал на **writecodeonline**.  
Потом перепроверил на **ideone** и изменил ответ.

Comment: @VenZell, вот и замечательно, получите плюсик ;)

Comment: По юникоду спасибо!
А если я работаю с cp1251? - там вылазит та же проблема (использую /i)

Comment: @Garfild, у вас файл в кодировке cp1251? Я правильно понял?

Comment: да, второй вариант, если ВСЁ в кодировке cp1251 (изначально тестил именно так, потом всё перекодировал в utf-8 - не спасло. а неплохо бы работать в cp1251 в данном проекте)

Comment: @Garfild, по идее, перекодировка строки для проверки в UTF-8 с помощью **iconv** должна вас спасти. Что-то вроде такого:  

    if(!preg_match('/^[а-я]*$/iu', iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $name))

Comment: прошу прощения, возможно неправильно выразился.
второй вариант, когда и файл и всё остальное, ВСЁ находится в cp1251. или несмотря на это всё равно там откуда-то берётся utf8?
или вы имеете ввиду перекодировывать в utf8 на время проверки и потом обратно?

Comment: @Garfild, к сожалению, только окольными путями (но не обязательно такими). Зависит от вашей задачи.